# What are the differences between @use and @forward in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

`@use` and `@forward` both rules can load  mixins, functions, and variables from other Sass stylesheets, and combines CSS from multiple stylesheets together. But i was wondering what are the differences between them and when to use which one?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Both `@use` and `@forward` are the alternatives provided by Dart sass for importing other stylesheets. When `@import` exposes the members such as variables, mixins, and functions globally accessible, `@use` loads them with the namespace. Hence, sass encourages using `@use` over `@import`.

Coming to the other, the `@forward` is paired with `@use`. For example, when a group of stylesheets have to be reused across multiple stylesheets, we can merge all of them into a single entry point using `@forward` and make use of `@use` to consume in the other stylesheets.

```
   // src/_list.scss
   @mixin list-reset {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
    }

   // bootstrap.scss
   @forward "src/list";

   // styles.scss
   @use "bootstrap";
   li {
    @include bootstrap.list-reset;
   }
```

In the above example, if you try to use `@use` in place of `@forward`, the members in the _list.scss may be available for bootstrap.scss but styles.scs cannot access it.